# How to log errors with traces but without setting the `err` field?

Tags: logging, rust, error-handling

My handler function has a step that determines whether an API key is valid. If invalid, it logs that as an error. This generates a lot of noise in errors in Datadog.

My objective is to only warn over the failed authentication instead of marking it as error. This made me to not use the `?` to propagate error and instead handle it manually, using the `warn!`. I also had to remove the `err` from the `instrument` `proc_macro`.

Now I get the desired green signal in datadog for the above failed authentication, and red where the function should actually fail (a name validity check). However, in the latter, no error is logged. This makes me think that removing the `err` will not log any error.

Is there any way to log the error without the `err` field set for indexing in the `tracing` macro?

My code:

```
#[instrument(
    name = "ControlPlane.global.create",
    fields(index_name, project, environment),
    skip_all
)]
async fn create(
    state: State<GlobalAppState>,
    api_key: APIKey,
    headers: HeaderMap,
    index: LoggingJson<GlobalCreateIndexRequest>,
) -> Result<(StatusCode, Json<GlobalIndexMetadata>), ServerError> {
    let project_id = match authenticate(state.clone(), &api_key).await {
        Ok(id) => id,
        Err(e) => {
            let log_message = format!(
                "Authentication error in ControlPlane.global.create: code={:?}, message={:?}",
                e.error.code, e.error.message
            );
            if e.error.code == ErrorCode::Unauthenticated {
                warn!(log_message);
            } else {
                error!(log_message);
            }
            return Err(e);
        }
    };

    let name = index.0.name.as_str();

    if let Err(e) = is_valid_resource_name(name) {
        let error_message = format!("Invalid index name: {:?}", e);
        error!(error_message);
        
        record!(
            "error" => &format!("{:?}", e)
        );
        return Err(e.into());
    }

<other parts of the handler>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the effective outcome is on Datadog and what exact outcome you want. It comes up as red but no error message? Using `#[instrument]` with `err` just emits an `error!(error = ...)` event if the result is `Err`.

Comment: If I remove `err` from `#[instrument]`, and even if I manually log the error with `error!`, the trace is green. which i don't want it to be. I want to remove the `err` and have the trace as red when I use the `error!`

Comment: To be more clear, I don't think its the event level that triggers that. I think its the `error` *attribute* that triggers it (or possibly both), so you'd have to write `error!(error = "something")` like `#[instrument]` does.